# Dropzone is giving incorrect values in totaluploadprogress event

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dropzone.js

In my Dropzone implementation, on upload, I want to display a single progress bar for all files being uploaded.

When I upload 2 files of 20MB each in my Dropzone, the first totaluploadprogress event that is fired contains a totalBytes value of 40MB and a totalBytesSent of 0. All subsequent totaluploadprogress events contain the same totalBytes value and an incrementing totalBytesSent value, as expected.

However, when the first file has been uploaded, things change. The totalBytes drops by 20MB to 20MB and the totalBytesSent drops to 0.

Why does this happen? Is this a bug?

I expected totalBytes to stay at the value of 40MB and totalBytesSent reaching that same value in the end.